# Accounting for time with repeated-measures in lmer when not interested in time

Tags: time-series, lme4

I am trying to conduct a repeated-measures mixed-effects test with lmer and lmerTest, but I am not sure if I am doing it appropriately.

I have 6 sites with 3 plots per site that have been sampled once per year for 24 consecutive years. I have several environmental and species variables, but for simplicity, let's say I have two environmental variables (depth and temperature) and two species (species 1 and species 2). I am not interested in the time variable, changes with time, or the interactions, as this system has strong wet/dry seasonality where the effects of the dry season outweigh carry over effects of species from the prior year. I do not necessarily have data for all variables and plots every year, with some plots not sampled at times.

The question is whether species2 (a predator) has any effect on populations of species1, relative to the environmental variables.

Is it appropriate to include year as its own random effect in the model, along with plot within site?

```
model1 <- lmer(species1 ~ depth + temperature +  species2 + (1|year) + (1|site/plot), data=data)
```

For this particular analysis, there were 435 total observations (plot/year), but I worry that it is not appropriately conducting repeated-measures.

```
anova(model1)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
               Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
depth          0.0221  0.0221     1 145.75  0.0908    0.7635    
temperature    9.0213  9.0213     1 422.19 37.0429 2.596e-09 ***
species2       0.0597  0.0597     1 418.95  0.2450    0.6208
```

This does not seem right. Is the a better way to incorporate year, or should I include year at all?

If I exclude year, why does the DenDF for depth change so drastically?

```
model1 <- lmer(species1 ~ depth + temperature +  species2 + (1|year) + (1|site/plot), data=data)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
               Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF  F value    Pr(>F)    
depth          2.599   2.599     1 431.77   7.1096  0.007955 ** 
temperature    58.788  58.788    1 432.10 160.7955 < 2.2e-16 ***
species2       0.853   0.853     1 429.62   2.3336  0.127343    

summary(M1)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: species1 ~ depth + temperature + species2 + (1 | site/plot)
   Data: data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   833.4    861.9   -409.7    819.4      428 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.20675 -0.66119 -0.07051  0.52722  2.99942 

Random effects:
 Groups           Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 plot:site        (Intercept) 0.0003221 0.01795 
 site             (Intercept) 0.2051143 0.45290 
 Residual                     0.3656072 0.60465 
Number of obs: 435, groups:  plot:site, 24; site, 6

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         -0.538258   0.325072  50.071940  -1.656  0.10401    
depth                0.006338   0.002377 431.768539   2.666  0.00796 ** 
temperature          0.391023   0.030837 432.101095  12.681  < 2e-16 ***
species2            -0.353264   0.231252 429.615226  -1.528  0.12734    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) depth  temp
depth       -0.316              
temperature -0.467 -0.204       
specie2     -0.544  0.040  0.007
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have asked more questions than I answered, but I hope some of this is helpful.

*"The question is whether species2 (a predator) has any effect on populations of species1, relative to the environmental variables."*

I think when you word it this way, it is not entirely clear. Are you interested in the effect that species2 has on species1 - depending on what the environmental variables are (in other words the effect of species2 on species1 can change depending on depth or temperature? Or do you mean you would like to compare the effects of species2 on species1 to the effects of depth or temperature on species1? Or what do you mean, exactly, by *"relative to the environmental variables"*?

Yes, `(1|year) + (1|site/plot)` is a random intercept for both year and for plot within site. If you wanted a variable to be able to vary over each group (i.e. have a random slope) you would do something like `(Temperature|year) + (1|site/plot)` if you thought the effect of temperature on species1 might be different in different years.

Exactly how you specify the model is going to be based on your knowledge of the biological system and your knowledge of statistics. Based on the information in your question, this random effects formulation that you have suggested appears completely reasonable to me. Yes, this is allowing you to account for grouped data (grouped by each year and by each plot within site). It is possible that with only 435 observations you may have convergence issues with an overly complex model, which you may or may not have - just something to look out for.

I am not sure what you mean by "this does not seem right" - what are you expecting to see? What is missing?

I am seeing the same model twice (below), with different values as the output, is there a copy and pasting error here, or am I missing something? The values shouldn't be off with the same model structure.

```
model1 <- lmer(species1 ~ depth + temperature +  species2 + (1|year) + (1|site/plot), data=data)
```

You haven't removed `year` in the above line, but have below this in the `summary(M1)` call.

My simple answer about the year question would be yes, I would include year. Every year is so different in any biological dataset I have seen that it is worth including as a random intercept at least - exactly as you have done. If the variance of the random effect mean is estimated to be zero, then this term is as if you didn't have it there in the first place. At that point you can choose to fit that random effect as a fixed effect instead if you still would like to account for the grouped nature of the data.

Also, there are lots of resources on this. Some examples:

Bolker, Benjamin M., Mollie E. Brooks, Connie J. Clark, Shane W. Geange, John R. Poulsen, M. Henry H. Stevens, and Jada-Simone S. White. "[Generalized linear mixed models: a practical guide for ecology and evolution.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169534709000196)" Trends in ecology & evolution 24, no. 3 (2009): 127-135.

Harrison, Xavier A., Lynda Donaldson, Maria Eugenia Correa-Cano, Julian Evans, David N. Fisher, Cecily ED Goodwin, Beth S. Robinson, David J. Hodgson, and Richard Inger. "A brief introduction to mixed effects modelling and multi-model inference in ecology." PeerJ 6 (2018): e4794.
https://peerj.com/articles/4794/